# Image slider wont fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, slider, fade

I am trying to make a jquery image slider, but for some reason the fade in is not working. Here is my code:

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

function startSlider() {
    count = $('#slider>a').size();
    loop = setInterval(function() {


        if (sliderNext > count) {
            sliderNext = 1;
            sliderInt = 1;
        }

        $('#slider>a').fadeOut(1000);
        $('#slider>a#'+sliderNext).show('fade',1000);

        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
    },3000);
}

function stopLoop() {
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

$('#slider>a#1').fadeIn(1000);
    startSlider();
    $('#slider>a').hover(function() {
        stopLoop();
    },function() {
        startSlider();
});
```

The first fade in goes fine and the fade out always works, but the `$('#slider>a#'+sliderNext).fadeIn(1000);` does not work

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I think the problem is your

```
$('#slider>a#'+sliderNext).show('fade',1000);
```

You can't call `show()` like you did, passing in `fade`. Use `.fadeIn(1000)` instead. Also, you can simplify your selector to `$('#' + sliderNext')` since IDs are unique.
One other error I can see in your code is in your `startSlider` function, you need to init `sliderNext` to `2`, not `1`.

**Edit 2:** the problem in your fiddle is that during the fade transition, both the image fading in and the image fading out are being displayed. The image that is fading in is being cut off by the `overflow: hidden`. Once the old image finishes fading out, the new image moves left to take the space where the old image was. (I hope that makes sense). So the new image *is* fading in, it's just cut off. You can fix it by putting the `fadeIn()` inside a callback function of the `fadeOut()`, like

```
$('#slider > a').fadeOut(1000,function(){
  $('#slider>a#'+sliderNext).show('fade',1000);
})
```

Comment: yh i did that but forgot to put them in the post. now there in

Comment: here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wwPu/). and slidernext should be set to one otherwise it skips the first image

Comment: You might want to look at using the jQuery cycle plugin. That might be easier. http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/